# Making many replier sockets in the server side of a ZeroMQ REQ/REP pattern, using threads

Tags: python, multithreading, networking, zeromq

For reasons of my work, using ZeroMQ `REQ/REP` pattern, I decided to make the replier work of the server in a different thread from the principal. The code that I'm going to show summarize that approach:

```
import time
import zmq
import threading


def make_work(context):
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
    socket.bind("tcp://*:5555")

    message = socket.recv()
    print("Received request: %s" % message)

    #Do some 'work'
    time.sleep(1)

    #Send reply back to client
    socket.send(b"World")
    socket.close()



 context = zmq.Context()
 thr = None

 while True:

    if not thr or not thr.is_alive():

        thr = threading.Thread(target = make_work, args = (context, ) )
        thr.start()
```

I modified the hello world example of the pyzmq guide. So, my problem is that when I run the hello world client from the doc made by Pieter Hintjens, the expected behavior is : for each thread that I'm creating, the replier socket that I open, sends the answer to the client, but the real behavior is, that after the first thread, both sides of the connection blocks. If I make a poll in the client side, and retry to send, it's success, but this is not that I want. It is possible a successful receive in the server side, in the new thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q** : *It is possible a successful receive in the server side, in the new thread?*

Yes, it is.

Your half of the code ( client still invisible ) suffers from very low efficiency. It takes some time to create + setup + self-establish a **[distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing)** infrastructure ( re-instantiate a `Socket`-instance, configure its local side, ask O/S to provide a port for `.bind()`, wait for others to successfully detect a presence of a new counterparty to `.connect()` and actually do a `.connect()` to setup and negotiate a ling there and back ...), **all that done for but a one message and `.close()`?**

Well, if one wishes.

Smart systems re-use resources without paying twice, the less many times, for what has already been paid for.

---

Plus, your infinite-loop "re-instated" thread takes additional side-effects you do not see from the code. Besides all the above sketched systematic ( yet each call re-repeated ) delays, there is one more, potentially forever blocking delay - the **`zmq.LINGER`** - a secret blocker.

Early versions of the ZeroMQ API worked with a default of `zmq.LINGER == -1` - being able to block inifitely long on the **`.close()`** method. More recent versions, the v4.3-stable for sure, use a `zmq.LINGER` default of `1000 [ms]`.

Anyway, a professional **[distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing)** design explicitly controls the instance parameters and sets the `.setsockopt( zmq.LINGER, 0 )` for safety purposes always and without exception.

If interested, feel free to read more details about other silent dangers of the **`REQ/REP`** mutual deadlocks in many other [ZeroMQ posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bzeromq%5D)

Comment: Hi, @user3666197 !, thanks for reading my post. One few more thinks about the problem. The client side of my code, as I specified in the post, is the hello world client of the doc made by Pieter Hintjens. My project is not a profesional one, is a briefcase project. Otherwise, thanks for the advice about ineficiency. On the other hand, in my original project I need avialability of the server side to keep recieving messages while I'm doing other activity, that it has to be with a requester socket. If I open a thread for each requester, and leave the replier socket in the original thread...

Comment: (and never close it until the program is running), I get the same inefficiency?